# How to read stream data from a TCP socket in Swift 2?

Tags: tcp, swift2

Let's suppose, I have a custom server that listens to connections on some port and once it has received a connection, it starts sending data (sort of a logger). Here's the first question:

Can it be just binary data? Actually, I need  just two non-zero 8-bit values, and I was thinking of 0-value byte to separate each new portion of data.

These three bytes will be sent once or may be twice a second.

So, now I am looking for some code snippet in Swift 2 to properly read this data. Normally, I would expect calling

```
connectSocket(IP,port)
```

which would connect to the socket, and once it receives the first chunk of data,

```
socketCallBack()
```

is called, or something like that.

Intuitively, I don't like the idea of checking data in a while (true) loop.  Or is this the proper way?

I've seen an example, when it first sends 'get' request to the server and immediately starts waiting for response. Probably, I can call it using a timer, once a second? Will it be correct?

What I am concerned about is trafic. Right now I have impemented it through a web-server, but I don't like that it spends way too much trafic for that overhead http data.

Probably, with that tcp connections on timer that would be much less, and it would save even more trafic if I establish just one connection in the beginning and transmit the data within this connection. Am I right?

Comment: Have you got it yet?